Is My Treelist Template Structure in Sitecore Correct?
I am currently in the process of learning Sitecore and have successfully created a dropdown menu utilizing the Treelist component. However, I would like to seek your guidance to ensure that my implementation aligns with best practices. Also, is Treelist an appropriate choice for this type of data field?
The template used contains single-line-text and general-link fields.

Here's the dropdown navigation menu


@Yash Gupta, Are you going to use the structure you provided above as the data source for the Treelist field in some page item?
What are you looking for here? Do you want to select a single item from the structure you have provided in your data source field?
Example: FirstItem to be selected in the Treelist Field.
But if you want multiple items to be selected then this is good.
If singleitem selection case I would suggest going with Droplink or Droplist field in your item template to select the structure you defined above.
Check Droplink, DropList, Multilist, TreeListEx, and finally Treelist, there are a lot of articles out there on these topics.
Note:
If you are talking about Sitecore content tree structure, it should not have only 2 fields that you have mentioned (usually it will have a lot of fields based on your requirements, and all the pages will not come from the same template),
but if you trying to create the navigation datasource then the above structure is fine, again all based on the requirement.

Thanks again, @Nelson. I have updated the question with the navigation menu image I am referring to; please take a look. Yes, I am using the same structure for the datasource.

This is good, you can use it, There is other options also like multi-list, explore that too.
For your requirement, Treelist suits fine, but if you targeting from one node and its immediate children Multilist is the proper choice, here in multilist you cant see tree structure for selection.
Just explore all the fields I have mentioned above, it will really help you

Thank you, @Nelson, for all your detailed answers and guidance. I will surely explore other link types too. Thanks again
